# Finding an explicit expression for a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am looking for a method (if it even exists) to find the closed form for sequences like :

$u_{n+2}=\sqrt{\alpha u_{n+1}+ \beta u{n}}$ with $\alpha,\beta,u_0,u_1>0$

I already know a method exists for the sequences with a *product* inside the square root, such as :

$u_{n+2}=\lambda\sqrt{u_{n+1}*u{n}}$ with $\lambda,u_0,u_1>0$

(which consists in taking the logarithm and solving a "discrete differential equation", and then applying a certain theorem whose name is unknown to me, but is very useful)

The main problem comes from the fact that if a product is in the square root, it is easy to derive another sequence which can be expressed in "polynomial form" ($v_{n+2}=\frac{1}{2}v_{n+1}+\frac{1}{2}v_n+ln(\lambda)$), which can't seem to be done when there is a sum in the square root.

Any idea for this one ? (Squaring doesn't work either since we turn the right side of the equation from the square root of a sum to a sum of square roots, which still isn't in the polynomial form)

Thank you very much